# Some issues with understanding functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Define echo
def echo(n):
    """Return the inner_echo function."""

    # Define inner_echo
    def inner_echo(word1):
        """Concatenate n copies of word1."""
        echo_word = word1 * n
        return echo_word

    # Return inner_echo
    return inner_echo

# Call echo: twice
twice = echo(2)

# Call echo: thrice
thrice = echo(3)


# Call twice() and thrice() then print
print(twice('hello'), thrice('hello'))
```

I do not understand the last line:`Print(twice('hello'), thrice('hello'))`.

How can I pass an argument to a variable twice or thrice, there is no placeholders for arguments like functions have?

Comment: `echo` is an [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) i.e. a function that either takes other functions as arguments or return functions as result.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think `echo` is partially evaluated. This is *not* the mechanism taking place here.

What happens in your code is that the object returned is itself a function that can in turn be called. We call functions that return functions *higher order functions*.

To convince yourself that the function `echo` returns is indeed the `inner_echo` function, try the following experiment

```
def echo(n):
    def inner_echo(word1):
        return word1 * n
    return inner_echo

twice = echo(2)
print(twice)
```

#### Output

```
<function echo.<locals>.inner_echo at 0x000002437BA36A60>
```

What this tells us is that `twice` is indeed a function. Furthermore, it is currently stored in the local variables of an `echo` call. Finally its name is indeed `inner_echo`.

### Partial evaluation

As mentionned, what takes place in your code is not partial evaluation. By example, in your actual code, this would not work.

```
echo('foo', 2) # TypeError
```

If it were you would have to define `echo` like so.

```
from functools import partial

@partial
def echo(n, word):
    print(word * n)

echo('foo', 2)
echo('bar')(3)
```